# Can I install the sdk for Samsung Smart TV into an existing eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, samsung-smart-tv

I've installed the [Samsung Smart TV SDK](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/Sdkdownload) but when I launch eclipse it doesn't have the Samsung SDK tools menu, or any tv related stuff.  Is it possible that one of the other versions of eclipse I have installed are affecting it?  I have the same problem with both version 4 and 3.5.2 of the sdk.

Alternatively can I just install the sdk into my pre-existing eclipse install?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you run eclipse.exe as an administrator, per installation instructions?
If not, right click on eclipse.exe and select "Run as administrator" from the context menu.

Samsung features are only installed when doing so.
After opening Eclipse once as administrator the features are installed, and will be available even if you execute it as a regular user.

Comment: No problem. Actually, i missed that part as well at first.