# Samsung SDK 4 Eclipse Missing Plugins

Tags: eclipse, sdk, samsung-smart-tv

I just installed SDK version 4 and the eclipse IDE doesn't have any of the Samsung plugins, it  seems to be a simple basic JAVA edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you must open eclipse using administrator rights, I found the answer in another question "[Can I install the sdk for Samsung Smart TV into an existing eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312950/can-i-install-the-sdk-for-samsung-smart-tv-into-an-existing-eclipse?rq=1)", but the question itself isn't specifically to this problem.